# Importing custom modules

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to organize my project and following is the hierarchy of the project:

```
-Project
   --core
     |--__init__.py
     |--module_1.py
     |--module_2.py
   --env1
     |--env1.py
   --env2
     |--env2.py
```

The project has multiple environments and all of them share the modules in the core directory. I am trying to import `function1` from `module1` in `env1.py` and `env2.py`:

```
from core.module_1 import function1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

I also tried setting the path of the core directory but no luck. The `import` works if the module is in the same directory as the script calling it or if the script calling the module is in the main directory (in my case, `Project`). How do I import the modules from the `core` directory to the environment directories?

Comment: have you tried with .core.module1?

Comment: yes tried this, it is throwing error;No module named '__main__.core';

Answer (score 2):

You've got the exact same problem that has been causing me trouble for a lot of last week. Here's my final version. If somehow this creates a time-machine, send that function back to me from last week, would ya?

```
def load_function(filepath,func_name) -> "function":
    """Load any function from a given path to a .py script."""
    return getattr(__import__(filepath,fromlist=[func_name]),func_name)
```